# Вывод даты в php из mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Добрый день! у меня такой вопрос. Мне нужно вывести дату из бд - там задан формат y-m-d
тип -date, ну тут нет ничего сложного я использую foreach вывод всех данных.

```
 <?=$row->disla_date ?>
```

только мне нужно чтобы вывод был d.m.y
я думала, что если поставить

```
<?=date("d.m.y", $row->disla_date)?>
```

это естественно не помогло, как мне поменять?
За ранее спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
<?=date("d.m.y", strtotime($row->disla_date))?>
```

Comment: спасибо, помогло.